# How can you store text in a blobstore in GAE/Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

+++ It is working - See solution at bottom +++

I am a relative newbie to Google App Engine and Python.

I have some large text content (content in a variable and not an external file) that I am manipulating in my program.  GAE does not let me write to files so I would like to store them in blobstore.  Can I do this in GAE and Python? and if so, how?

An example code snippet would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

+++ Updated Question +++

I tried following the example at the link you provided modified by the example at: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-Part-1 to enable the saving of the blobstore key in the datastore.  When the time comes to retrieve the file (which is an html file), I want to retrieve the BlobKey using the TemplateName.

I ended up with something like this:

In models.py I have:

```
class GeneratedFiles(ndb.Model):
  TemplateName = ndb.StringProperty()
  BlobKey = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
  Status = ndb.StringProperty(default="Pending Translation")
```

In a class, in a .py file I have:

```
class TokenFileGen(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template(FileName)     
        blobtext = template.render(tokenvals = tokendict)
        bloboutput = (blobtext.encode('utf-8'))
        # Create the file
        file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')
        # Open the file and write to it
        with files.open(file_name, 'a') as fl:
            fl.write(bloboutput)
        # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
        files.finalize(file_name)
        # Get the file's blob key
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
        logging.info('QQQ: blob_key: %s' % blob_key)
        f = GeneratedFiles(
            TemplateName = templateName
            , BlobKey = blob_key                       
            , Status = 'Published'
            )
        f.put()
        ...
```

I get a TypeError('Cannot set non-property %s' % name) TypeError: Cannot set non-property blob

My logging statement returned the following:
INFO     2012-09-21 05:20:24,177 token.py:551] QQQ: blob_key: vL117vQ4dlIPoUwXbREmbeqUnZU7nJ6ELMma8u1bFHGUfgEfOfS7HfAdFUvXc1EC

I thought I was following the example fairly closely.  Any idea how I can get this to work?

Thanks for any assistance.

+++ update 2 +++

Ok, I am now able to save the Blobstore reference in the following model:

```
class GeneratedFiles(ndb.Model):
  TemplateName = ndb.StringProperty()
  BlobKey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
```

The code that saved this is:

```
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as fl:
    fl.write(bloboutput)
files.finalize(file_name)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
logging.info('QQQ: blob_key: %s' % blob_key)
f = GeneratedFiles(
    TemplateName = templateName
    , BlobKey = blob_key                       
    )
f.put()
```

I am now trying to retrieve and download the file:

```
class FileDownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, genfile_id):
        iden = int(genfile_id)
        file_info = ndb.Key('GeneratedFiles', iden).get()
        if not file_info or not file_info.BlobKey:
            self.error(404)
            return
        else:
            blob_key = file_info.BlobKey
        logging.info('QQQ: FileDownloadHandler/blob_key: %s' % blob_key)
        self.send_blob(blob_key, save_as=True)
```

I am getting a error: ValueError: Expected BlobInfo value for blob_key_or_info. on the last line.

Just prior to the error msg, I get my log info:

```
INFO     2012-09-21 19:19:44,219 genfile.py:131] QQQ: FileDownloadHandler/blob_key: sGxZRNu94u1kZ9ezpAeQFhyOLSZFYNX8RSAbXU78MLjjUKOohV0wyWnZZEQf6ScC
```

I found some references that mention URLencoding in conjunction with this error.  Could this be the problem?  If so, what would URLencoding look like in my case and where should I place it (when I store the blob_key or after I retrieve id from ndb.datastore?

Thanks for any assistance.

+++ the solution +++

The key was changing the self.send_blob statement as follows (referencing blobstore and BlobInfo).

```
self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo(file_info.blob), save_as=True)
```

I also changed the name of the attribute BlobKey to blob (was getting an error and error went away after I did this although I do not understand why that would make a difference).

Comment: You use NDB. You have to use BlobKeyProperty, see the NDB documentation

Comment: Thanks.  With that the save now works.  However when I try to use the key, I get an "Expected BlobInfo value for blob_key_or_info" error.  I posted latest code and logs and msgs in update 2 to question.  Further wisdom would be appreciated.  (Sorry to be asking so many basic questions.  I am a retired web app architect trying to help a non-profit with zero funding get some functionality.  I have some old programming skills (Classic ASP and old VB).  Thanks for being patient and providing code examples.)

Comment: Sometimes you have to use the blob_key and sometimes blob_info. You can convert between those two. See the documentation.
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)

Comment: I am not sure where that would go.  I apparently have successfully retrieved the blob_key but it is not being accepted when I try to use the key in the "self.send_blob(blob_key, save_as=True)" statement.  All the documentation examples other than the one you sent me the link to earlier, relate to upload cases.  Are you suggesting the key I stored is not stored correctly or that the key I retrieve from ndb has to first be modified somehow.  Thanks.

Comment: I have these lines:
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(key) 
        self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at writing to the blobstore: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

You can give votes to comments as well.

Comment: Thank you. I should have seen this on my own but I had received suggestions from others that pointed me to more complex upload examples that did not help me.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried following the example (modified by need to store the blob_key for later retrieval).  It is not working.  Please see the updated question for details.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure how this voting and declaring answers to be correct works.  But I now realize that I can vote more for an answer.  I would like to vote this answer higher but you will have to make a small edit to the answer for me to do that.  Thanks greatly for all your help.